# adding list item with angular animations

Tags: angular-animations

I m trying to animate a list which is made with ngFor. When dynamically a new item is added to the array, i want to have the animation bellow. Somehow i cant get this rolling effect. Any ideas what am i doing wrong ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'widget',
  templateUrl: './widget.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget.component.scss'],

  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}),
        animate('800ms ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

html

```
 <div *ngFor="let winner of widgetService.winners; let i = index"
                 class="winners__item" [@slideInOut]>
                <img [src]="winner.imageUrl" alt="{{ winner.gameName }}">
                <div class="block__container--first">
                    <div class="block__container--first--gameName">{{winner.gameName}}</div>
                    <div class="block__container--first--firstName">{{winner.firstName}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="block__container--second">
                    <div class="block__container--second--timestamp">{{winner.timestamp}}m ago</div>
                    <div class="block__container--second--winning">{{winner.amount}} €</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

what i have:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

what i tried:

```
 animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({marginTop: '-100px'}),
        animate('800ms ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Comment: What are you getting right now?

Comment: @Jozott added in the description

Comment: They are jumping down if the new element appears, because the new element takes the space, since your animation with `transition` has no impact to the actual space that the new item takes. You could give the new item a negative top margin, so the item is actually above the list, and pushes the following items down. So instead of `transform: 'translateY(-100%)'` use `margin-top: '-100%'`.

Comment: @Jozott didnt work :(

Comment: What was the outcome?

Comment: @Jozott i added in the description

Comment: You need to use `margin-top: '0px'` in `animate()` as well

Comment: @Jozott thanks a lot man, you saved me :)

Comment: Does it work? ^^ I will write a full answer to this question for other people

Comment: yes it works.. please write the full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements jump down because the new element takes the first place. `transform: translate()` does not change the place behavior of the element, but only the visible position, without affecting other elements.

So to actual change the space of all elements, we need something like margin.

```js
animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({marginTop: '-100%'}),
        animate('800ms ease-in-out', style({marginTop: '0px'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

With this, the new item is placed above the list and pushes all following elements down when it moves.